# javascript - html interface to change global variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I would like to make a html interface to change values of global variables in another .js file.

In that html interface, there will be couple of text inputs one submit button and restore button. When user changes particular values and push OK button the global variables inside that .js file will be updated. So they will not change back when my webapp reloads.

I would like to have there also a RESTORE button to restore last state of variables (before last change). This interface could make a backup of variables when hitting OK button.

Is something like this possible? I dont like to ask such a broad and abstract question, but I will appreciate any starting info.

I know that more efficient way would be to use MySQL and php. Now I have to do it with javascript.

Comment: dependent only on JS then go for localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

To have a variable all through the session, you should maintain that in server side, by triggering AJAX calls. In server side you can maintain old value, as well as new value. And from HTML you can change it or restore it on demand

Comment: I am not familiar with AJAX. Can you be more specific on this? What is  the difference between your approach and using javascript localstorage?

Comment: store variables in the server (if u want the variable to persisted all through the session). update the variables from javascript to server through AJAX calls and retrieve the same using AJAX calls, whenever necessary .. If you are not aware of AJAX then please go-through it.

Comment: by storing tohse variables in the server you mean MySQL?

Comment: Server, dude, server !!!!!! Please understand J2EE / Enterprise application concepts first of all